# There's a 112V voltage (AC) between my 8-port switch and the radiator in the room. Is this problematic?

Tags: switch, lan

Yesterday I've ordered a new switch for my PC-setup at home, because the old one was only a 100Mbit-switch and we got a 200Mbit internet-line this week.

("D-Link 8 Port Gigabit Unmanaged Metal Desktop Switch (DGS-108)")

When I was about to connect it, I repeatedly received electric shocks. When I touched the metal casing of the switch, the LAN cables, and anything grounded at the same time. Like the PC casing, or the radiator.

That happened even when the power-line of the switch wasn't plugged in yet.

So I decided to ground the casing of the switch. But when I did so, and connected it to the radiator using a thick grounding cable from the hardware store, I noticed flying sparks when I connected it. And so I decided to measure the current.

At first I couldn't find any readings, and went on with the installation.
But when the electric shocks wouldn't stop, I decided to make one final measurement, that was when I measured 112V AC, at about 2.5mA.
(I live in Germany, where the power lines in homes usually have between 220V and 230V).

I have ordered a new switch from Amazon, but I suspect that there is some stray electric (compensating) current going through the shielding of my LAN cables.

Is this something I should be worried about? Or can I just leave the casing of the switch grounded/connected to the radiator, and ignore it?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking adn consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this questions on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage per-se isn't a problem, it's quite normal for class 2 devices to have a voltage on the case.

What is a problem is the "touch current". That is the current that flows when someone touches both the case of the appliance and an earthed metal object. I'm not 100% sure what the limit for touch current on regular portable appliance is but I think it's arround 0.25mA, your measurement of 2.5ma is ten times that.

Return the device as faulty.